# Print table with empty columns for consecutive delimiters

Tags: shell, text-formatting, columns

I typically use `column` to convert input into a table, eg:

```
$ echo 'a\tb\tc\nd\te\tf' | column -t -s $'\t'
a  b  c
d  e  f
```

However it collapses empty columns eg:

```
$ echo 'a\tb\tc\nd\t\tf' | column -t -s $'\t'
a  b  c
d  f
```

Rather than printing an empty column when there are consecutive delimiters. This is what I would like, using `column` or otherwise:

```
a  b  c
d     f
```

Comment: Instead of `echo` try `printf`

Comment: The questioner is clearly using a shell where `-e` is implied.  We have a whole family of duplicate Q&As about _that_, starting from  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/ .  But that is _not_ the focus of this question, which is about the `column` command.  Imagine that the input of the `column` command is _whatever is necessary_ to yield TAB-delimited fields within LF-delimited records, some of which are empty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use `GNU column`:

> **-n**
>   By default, the column command will merge multiple adjacent delimiters into a single delimiter when using the -t option; this option disables that behavior. This option is a Debian GNU/Linux extension.

```
printf 'a\tb\tc\nd\t\tf\n'  | column -t -n -s $'\t'
```

Output:

```
a  b  c
d     f
```

---

If `GNU column` is not available, you can use sed to add a space (or something else, e.g. a `-`) between the tabs:

```
printf 'a\tb\tc\nd\t\tf\n'  | sed -e ':loop; s/\t\t/\t-\t/; t loop' | column -t -s $'\t'
```

Comment: Thanks for the sed suggestion! I'm using Mac OS X so don't have GNU column or GNU sed, so this is what ended up working for me: ```printf 'a\tb\tc\nd\t\tf\n' | sed -$'s/\t\t/\t-\t/g' | column -t -s $'\t'```

Answer (score 1):

I couldnt find the -n option in my column command version, so fixed it using sed:

`echo -e 'a\tb\tc\nd\t\tf' | sed 's/\t\t/\t \t/'| column -t -s $'\t'`

Answer (score 0):

For those without GNU column (e.g. MacOS): be careful about first and last column. **If the first column is not the longest**, there would be a shift. The loop in the script didn't seem to be needed.
I suggest the following pipe: `| sed $'s/^\t/-\t/;s/\t\t/\t-\t/g;s/\t$/\t-/' | column -t`

```bsh
paste \
<(printf "a\nb\nc") \
<(printf "1\n2\n3\n4444\n5\n6") \
<(printf "d\ne\nf\ng\nh\ni\nj\nijkl\nk\nl") \
<(printf "X") \
\
| sed $'s/^\t/-\t/;s/\t\t/\t-\t/g;s/\t$/\t-/' | column -t
```

```
a  1     d     X
b  2     e     -
c  3     f     -
-  4444  g     -
-  5     h     -
-  6     i     -
-  -     j     -
-  -     ijkl  -
-  -     k     -
-  -     l     -
```

Comment: (1) We prefer each answer to be self-contained. Your post does provide enough new information that I support keeping it as a separate answer. However, it does talk about the other answer; you should explicitly say, from the start, that you are critiquing another answer. (2) I don’t understand what you’re saying about “If the first column is not the longest”; can you explain that more clearly? (3) Unless I’m overlooking something, your answer fails when there are three tabs in a row. That’s why the other answer used a loop.